# CSSで空白を挿入する方法

Tags: html, css, html5

```
<div class='a'>
 <span class='b'>1</span>
 <span class='c'>いい天気</span>
<div>
```

このようなhtmlがあって

```
1いい天気
```

と表示されます。

これをCSSを編集することで

```
1　いい天気
```

のように間にスペースほどの間隔を空けることは可能ですか？
(HTMLは編集できないようになっています。)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

可能です。

ひとつの方法として、 **`margin`** もしくは **`padding` プロパティ**で一文字分の余白を開ける、という方法があります。 `margin` と `padding` プロパティのどちらを用いるかは、その余白が要素の周囲に存在するものか、内部に存在するかで使い分けます。

`margin` プロパティを用いた例:

```css
.cap {
  margin-left: 1cap;
}

.ch {
  margin-left: 1ch;
}

.em {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.ex {
  margin-left: 1ex;
}

.ic {
  margin-left: 1ic;
}
```

```html
<h2>margin + cap</h2>
<div class='a'>
  <span class='b'>1</span>
  <span class='c cap'>いい天気</span>
</div>
<h2>margin + ch</h2>
<div class='a'>
  <span class='b'>1</span>
  <span class='c ch'>いい天気</span>
</div>
<h2>margin + em</h2>
<div class='a'>
  <span class='b'>1</span>
  <span class='c em'>いい天気</span>
</div>
<h2>margin + ex</h2>
<div class='a'>
  <span class='b'>1</span>
  <span class='c ex'>いい天気</span>
</div>
<h2>margin + ic</h2>
<div class='a'>
  <span class='b'>1</span>
  <span class='c ic'>いい天気</span>
</div>
```

`padding` プロパティを用いた例:

```css
.cap {
  padding-left: 1cap;
}

.ch {
  padding-left: 1ch;
}

.em {
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.ex {
  padding-left: 1ex;
}

.ic {
  padding-left: 1ic;
}
```

```html
<h2>padding + cap</h2>
<div class='a'>
  <span class='b'>1</span>
  <span class='c cap'>いい天気</span>
</div>
<h2>padding + ch</h2>
<div class='a'>
  <span class='b'>1</span>
  <span class='c ch'>いい天気</span>
</div>
<h2>padding + em</h2>
<div class='a'>
  <span class='b'>1</span>
  <span class='c em'>いい天気</span>
</div>
<h2>padding + ex</h2>
<div class='a'>
  <span class='b'>1</span>
  <span class='c ex'>いい天気</span>
</div>
<h2>padding + ic</h2>
<div class='a'>
  <span class='b'>1</span>
  <span class='c ic'>いい天気</span>
</div>
```

---

もうひとつの方法として、 `::before`, `::after` 疑似要素と `content` プロパティを組み合わせ、一文字分の**余白に該当する文字で要素を置き換える**方法があります。

```css
.nbsp::before {
  content: "\00a0";
}

.ideographic::before {
  content: "\3000";
}

.zero::before {
  content: "\200b";
}
```

```html
<h2>NO-BREAK SPACE</h2>
<div class='a'>
 <span class='b'>1</span>
 <span class='c nbsp'>いい天気</span>
</div>
<h2>IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE </h2>
<div class='a'>
 <span class='b'>1</span>
 <span class='c ideographic'>いい天気</span>
</div>
<h2>ZERO WIDTH SPACE</h2>
<div class='a'>
 <span class='b'>1</span>
 <span class='c zero'>いい天気</span>
</div>
```

Comment: なるほど。margin、paddingでこれほどの種類があるとは。。例もとても見やすかったです。ありがとうございました！